# C#.NET - getting error in ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c#-4.0

How to fix reading

Error here

```
ReadProcessMemory(hProc, ptr, buffer, buffer.Length, out var read);
```

Code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

public static IntPtr FindDMAAddy(IntPtr hProc, IntPtr ptr, int[] offsets)
{
    var buffer = new byte[IntPtr.Size];

    foreach (int i in offsets)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, ptr, buffer, buffer.Length, out var read);

        ptr = (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            ? IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)), i)
            : ptr = IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0)), i);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm always surprised when I see my code on here.  The code your using is identical to mine and it works fine for me on multiple projects.  First thing, your pointer chain must be correct or else it won't work.  Second you must run your application as administrator.  Third you must compile your .exe for the same architecture as the target process.  If the target process is x86 then compile for the same, likewise with x64.

If all these steps are completed, it will work fine as long as the target process does not have anticheat.